# Save UIView as xml

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, xcode5

I am able to load viewcontrollers from storyboards using

```
UIStoryboard *externalStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Test" bundle:bundle];
UIViewController *viewController = [externalStoryBoard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

However, I am manipulating the UIView via an editor and saving the changes, the UIStoryboard is made up as an xml file like below

```
<viewController id="iJz-N7-q33" sceneMemberID="viewController">
<layoutGuides>
<viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="dza-Zj-Nm3"/>
<viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="PHV-qg-hU8"/>
</layoutGuides>
<view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="g1l-Wr-I3I">
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="768" height="1024"/>
</view>
```

Is it possible to take a UIView and save the output to an xml file in this format?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically it is possible, yes (Xcode Interface Builder does it for you). Is there an API for it, yes and no. There is no direct API available, but there is a command line tool that you can use in OS X called [ibtool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ibtool.1.html) which can read and update Interface Builder documents (XIB / NIB files). You can't supply it with a view though. The closest you can likely get is to write your own XML export and use ibtool to verify what you've done.

[This site](http://www.monobjc.net/xib-file-format) may also be useful to you.